# Can I deploy an Ionic 4+ App (Angular + Capacitor) into ios App Store?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, app-store

I am currently developing a mobile app in Ionic 4+ (Angular + Capacitor) for Android and iOS.

However, I've considered bringing this app into the Apple App Store because I've read a lot about the UIWebView not being accepted by Apple.

Now my question: Are there any problems when publishing an Ionic 4+ (Angular + Capacitor) app to the App Store because of the UIWebView or was this problem avoided by using Capacitor?

I am very grateful for any advice! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 4th, 2019, Capacitor does not have references to UIWebView.

See here for more info: https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Comment: Thank you! This means that there should be no problems with the publication in the AppStore regarding the WebView.

Comment: Correct. See also: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-and-cordovas-future-in-apple-app-store/177794